# Как проверить изменения в диске

Tags: php, yandex-disk

Пишу  веб приложение на PHP, возника задача синхронизировать яндекс диск с сервером с помощью Rest Api, но вот как сделать если я загружаю файл на яндекс диск, то информация о том что в диске появился новый файл должна поступить на мой сервер?

Не делать же чтобы через каждую секунду отправлялся Http запрос и получал список файлов и проверял изменения?

В клиенте яндека диска для пк есть штука которая мне нужна, если я загружу файл с веб версии, то его тут же видно, что он появился в версии для пк и при этом не нужно нажимать кнопку обновить!

Как сделать нечто похожее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае либо периодически проверять (допустим раз в 30 секунд) новые файлы в списке последних загруженных.

https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/api/reference/recent-upload-docpage/

Либо написать свою форму загрузки файлов на яндекс.диск, убрать у пользователей возможность каким-либо иным образом загружать файлы на диск (не давать никому прямых доступов к диску, только через вашу форму) и по 201 ответу об успешной загрузке проводить необходимые вам изменения.

https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/api/reference/upload-docpage/

Насколько я вижу в данный момент Callback запросов с яндекс диска к удаленному серверу об успешной загрузке файла нет.

Comment: А как можно проверить новые папки?

Comment: В стандартной документации ничего не нашел. Попробуйте прикрутить SDK для php. 

Например этот:https://github.com/jack-theripper/yandex
или этот: https://github.com/leonied7/yandex-disk-api

И ещё вот сюда посмотрите: https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/231495/ (но тут кажется во-первых, для всего подряд (не только диска), документация попроще, так и не понял бегло есть ли решение этой задачи).